# Trying to export data in MySQL Workbench : mysqldump Version Mismatch

Tags: mysql

Help I keep getting this error when I try to export data:

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You seem to connect to a mariadb server with mysql tools. Mariadb is not mysql, it is a fork of mysql. Use their client tools instead of mysql's.

Comment: Did you migrate from mysql to mariadb?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes.. so it's not possible to export data from mysql workbench?

Comment: No at all the message is telling you what you should do.

Comment: @P.Salmon I already followed the instructions and set the path to the dump tool in the path to mysqldump but it still kept giving me the same error

Comment: Let me repeat: you are using mysql tools with mariadb. You need tools that are specifically designed for mariadb. Mysql workbench is not such tool.

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways in order to match it with, dump fil is basically a set of queries been written, if you will open mysql dump file in any text editor preferably Notepad++ you will see mysqldump version on top, just change the version number as per your convenience and then save and try importing again. Normally the text will be like below format.

/*
Source Server         : localhost
Source Server Type    : MySQL
Source Server Version : 50639
Source Host           : localhost:3306
Source Schema         : db_name
Target Server Type    : MySQL
Target Server Version : 50639
File Encoding         : 65001

Date: 07/01/2021 16:27:06
*/

Comment: Looks dangerous to me..Are you sure this is safe.

Comment: How could this be dangerous?, just change version number, or you can also copy the queries from editor and put them in workbench query window, make sure that you have selected the correct database.